# Disable Web-scoped features on Web deletion

Tags: spweb, event-handlers, feature-receiver, site-deletion

I have a SPWeb ( http://example.com/site ), created used a custom web template,  with several features activated on its scope.

When I delete the SPWeb it would be desirable that all the features activated at http://example.com/site would be deactivated (therefore running the FeatureDeactivating events on all features at that scope).

Some quick testing showed that sharepoint does not deactivate those features automatically.

How can I achieve this behavior programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trap the WebDeleting method using a WebEventReceiver. Iterate over your activated features at that scope, then deactivate them.

Read more in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebeventreceiver.webdeleting(v=office.12).aspx (Note there's a version of that page for 2010 too).